# Custom Stripe Checkout button not opening window on mobile

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I'm aware of the issue concerning `handler.open` in anything but a click event, due to browser popup blockers, but please see the following code I am using:

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" data-stripe data-image="/path/to/image.jpg">The button</button>
```

**JS**

```
export function paymentScreen(form, response) {

  const restaurant = form.querySelector('[name="restaurant"]').value,
    guests = form.querySelector('[name="guests"]').value,
    time = form.querySelector('[name="time"]').value.split(':').slice(0, 2).join(':'),
    email = form.querySelector('[name="email"]').value,
    stripe = form.querySelector('[data-stripe]');

  const handler = window.StripeCheckout.configure({
    key: response.StripePublishableKey,
    name: `Dim t - ${restaurant}`,
    description: `Booking for ${guests} guests at ${time}`,
    amount: parseInt(response.PaymentAmount, 10),
    email: email,
    currency: 'GBP',
    locale: 'auto',
    token(stripeResponse) {
      stripePaymentProcess(form, response, stripeResponse);
    }
  });

  // This part fails, even though we're in a click event listener.
  stripe.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    handler.open({
      image: this.dataset.image,
      zipCode: false
    });
  });
}
```

The error I get in the console is as follows:

> Stripe Checkout was unable to open a new window, possibly due to a
>   popup blocker. To provide the best experience for your users, follow
>   the guide at
>   https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-more-runloop.

If I read the guide, I cannot see what I am doing wrong.

Any ideas on how to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: Can you please clarify what this is?

`form.querySelector('[data-stripe]')`

Comment: Sorry yes; it's simply getting a single button.